# How to show that $\frac{4^n}{n^{3/2}\sqrt \pi}$ could not be expressed as $\sum_i^m p_i(n)\lambda_i^n$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, number-theory, analysis

How to show that 
$$
\frac{4^n}{n^{3/2}\sqrt \pi}
$$ has not the form $p_1(n) \lambda_1^n + \ldots p_i(n) \lambda_i^{n}$ for some polynomials $p_i(n)$ and numbers $\lambda_i$?

Answer (score 3):

The Laplace transform of $p(x) K^x$ is a rational function whose singularities are poles.
The Laplace transform of $\frac{4^x}{x^{3/2}}$ has a branch point (of the $C\sqrt{s-2\log 2}$ kind) at $s=2\log 2$, hence $\frac{4^x}{x^{3/2}}$ and $\sum p_m(x) K_m^x$ cannot be the same function.

Comment: Just because this was mentioned without further explanation in a basic textbook. Is there a more elementary way to see it?

Comment: Jack: do you think you can show that not only the sequence is not rational, but that it's power series is not $D$-finite, in the kernel of some differential operator with polynomial coefficients?